# PowerShell loop to install multiple programs

Tags: windows, powershell

This script asks the user if they want to install a program.

```
$program = Read-Host -Prompt 'Would you like to install program? Please type Yes or No'
```

It is then lead to an If statement below

```
if ( $program -eq 'Yes' ) 
{
 start-process <exe file>
}
else
{
  Write-Host "Install <application> was skipped"
}
```

This is asked for multiple applications when prompted to install. The problem I have is that after it askes, The installation of all the applications happen at once. Is there a way to use a loop to install the first application then move on to the next? I am new to PowerShell so I am trying to make this effective.

Comment: Add `-wait` switch.  `start-process <exe file> -Wait`

Answer (score 0):

Set an array of links of apps that you want to install. You can use CSV

```
$import_CSV = Import-CSV "Path_to_file"
foreach($link in $import_CSV){ your code here  }
```

This would be kind of easy way to get you going.  `start-process <$link>` and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you, This is a great way looking into it

Comment: Would here still be a practical way without using a CSV file

Comment: @CoreyCBurton, where would you be getting the exe files from?

Comment: I mean you can store the Paths to .exe files directly into array. Then read it out - but that is just not readable.